# Merging files in reverse

Tags: linux, bash, glob

I am working on the logs, they are in multiple number.

lets assume the following files has the content

```
file1
1
file2
2
file3
3
```

by using the command `cat file*` the result would be

```
1
2
3
```

but i am looking for some thing , while i use the regex/command using `file*` i want the output to be some thing like this.

```
3
2
1
```

could some one help me please.

Comment: Maybe use `tac` ? Or just call the files in the opposite order.

Comment: Does each file have only a single line? `tac` would reverse the order of the lines in each file, as well as reversing the order in which the files appear.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the output of `cat` to `tac` :

```
$ cat file*
1
2
3

$ cat file* | tac
3
2
1
```

Answer (score 1):

You may call

```
ls -1r file* | xargs cat
```

in order to specify the order of the files. Its output is different from the `tac` solution, since each single logfile is in the correct order. (Perhaps this is not even the desired output).

Comment: `-1` is redundant when `ls` has something other than a terminal as standard output, but you shouldn't be using the output of `ls` in the first place.